# Node server working only on localhost Lumen

Tags: node.js, socket.io, lumen

I am making a real-time Lumen API. For that i have used Node.js to create the server.
It works perfectly fine on localhost, but not when published

This is the code for my **Node Server.js**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

app.listen(6001, function() {
    console.log('Server chalu hua');
});

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('');
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Lijiye Nya connection bna diya gya');
});

io.on('disconnect', function(socket) {
    console.log('Connection Dropped');
});

redis.psubscribe('*', function(err, count) {
    //
});

redis.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, message) {
    console.log(channel);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(message);
    io.emit(channel, message.data);
})
```

Can someone tell what to do, to make it work in Production

Comment: What exactly does not work in production?

Comment: The server refuse the connection.. checkout https://doorstep.000webhost.com:6001